# Good code sample in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been developing in rails for the past 1.5 years .. however , I feel my code is not upto the mark , and I still dont fully utilize all that Ruby and Rails have to offer .
I have gone through all the material that is available on the guide site , and have incorporated that in my code . However , every time I see someone else's code , I find out new things about the language like idiomatic syntax etc .  
I was wondering if there are some really good code samples of rails that people can refer which would help me speed up my progress in rails . It can be anything , like some open source plugin or a app that has really high code standards .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start from GitHub. There are tons of Rails plugins and apps available.
Here's just a few examples:

- [GemCutter](http://github.com/qrush/gemcutter)
- [Spree](http://github.com/railsdog/spree)
- [Fat Free CMS](http://github.com/michaeldv/fat_free_crm)
- [Insoshi](http://github.com/insoshi/insoshi)

Plugin authors

- [Thoughtbot](http://github.com/thoughtbot)
- [Ryan Bates](http://github.com/ryanb)
- [Bynarylogic](http://github.com/binarylogic)
- [Joshua Peek](http://github.com/josh/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply . In particular I am looking for suggestions on the plugins that you have personally seen and feel that the code is of high standard .

Comment: There are thousands of good plugins out of there. I added a few authors to give you an idea. For each author you can enjoy many different good plugins.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite and commonly used gem/ Rails plugin is `will_paginate`. Pagination is pretty common in any web applications.

[will_paginate is hosted on GitHub.](http://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/) It works as a standard gem.

If you want to learn about Rails plugin development including how to read the code, you might want to read [Plugin Patterns in Rails 2](http://peepcode.com/products/rails-2-plugin-patterns).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Mephisto, a blogging platform written in Rails: http://mephistoblog.com/